# How does shuffling make data identically distributed?

Tags: neural-network

It makes sense that gradient descent algorithms (like stochastic GD, mini batch GD) work better when we shuffle data. (It makes instances in a dataset `independent`) (for example if dataset sorted by labels, in each mini batch we have data that related to a specific class so weights prone to a class(we have weights and biases that minimizes loss function in respect to one of labels, ... that's make GD have more volatilities).
but how shuffling make instance in dataset `identically distributed`? and how it helps GD?

Comment: Can you share a source which states that shuffling makes data IID?

Comment: hmm. i read it in "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow, 2nd Edition by Aurélien Géron", page 416. he is also referencing to chaper 4 of the book.